# Subtle differences between java swing objects

Tags: java, swing, size, jpanel, preferredsize

I am having some difficulty figuring out why there is a difference between the results I see on the Title Screen and the Setup Screen. I copy/pasted the majority of the code before tweaking each... it clearly has to do with something in my outer frame, but I don't know what. The problem I am seeing is that although the Title Screen comes up at the correct size of 1024x768 with the background correctly displayed, the Setup Screen comes up as a very small window as though I had not just set it's size. The background image is also only shown in that sliver of space, even if the box is resized.

I have removed all of the elements inside of Title Screen but it still maintains its size. Can someone help? Thanks

OuterFrame

```
public class OuterFrame extends JFrame {

public OuterFrame(String windowHeading) {

int WIDTH = 1024;
int HEIGHT = 768;
final Dimension screenSize = new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT);

setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

JPanel title = new TitleScreen();
title.setLayout(new BoxLayout(title, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
JButton matchButton = new JButton("New Match");
    //Add action listener to button
    matchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //Execute when button is pressed
            removeAll();
            JPanel setupScreen = new SetupScreen();             

            add(setupScreen);
            pack();
        }
    });         
JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit to Windows");
    //Add action listener to button
    exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //Execute when button is pressed
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }); 
matchButton.setAlignmentX(title.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
exitButton.setAlignmentX(title.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

title.setPreferredSize(screenSize);
title.add(matchButton);
title.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,25)));
title.add(exitButton);

add(title);

pack();
}
}
```

Title Screen

```
public class TitleScreen extends JPanel {
public BufferedImage background;

public TitleScreen() {
    try {
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("images/datascreen.png"));
        Image image = ImageIO.read(is);
        background = (BufferedImage)image; 
    } catch (Exception a) {
    }
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

    g2.drawImage(background,0,0,1024,768,null);
}
}
```

SetupScreen

```
public class SetupScreen extends JPanel {
public BufferedImage background;

public SetupScreen() {
    try {
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("images/datascreen.png"));
        Image image = ImageIO.read(is);
        background = (BufferedImage)image; 
    } catch (Exception a) {
    }
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

    g2.drawImage(background,0,0,1024,768,null);
}
}
```

Sorry about the formatting.. I can't for the life of me make it keep the indention I use in my code.

Edit:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(1024, 768);
}
```

I added the above to both the title and the setup classes, as well as removing the hard coded resize. The issue still occurs - the window is sized correctly for the title but not the setup. Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: 1) By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`. 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for the basics. In this case the problem is that you don't override the getPreferredSize() method of your custom component, so the layout manager basically uses 0.

The reason your first screen displays is because you hardcoded:

```
title.setPreferredSize(screenSize);
```

This is a no-no (for too many reasons to go into detail here). The component should return its preferred size as mentioned above and then the pack() statement will work properly.

Comment: So rather than setting the preferred size, I should override the command which returns the size, telling it to just return the size I want rather than trying to figure it out?

Comment: I think I am repeating back to you what you just said there, but I want to make sure I understand what is going on here.

Comment: `telling it to just return the size I want rather than trying to figure it out?` - exactly, your custom painting code knows what the size should be. So this is the value that should be returned. This is the way all Swing components work.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that the problem was the removeAll() statement. I added getContentPane. to it and it worked fine.